# Distributed locust load testing on local machine

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I was wondering is it possible to run locust distributed on the local machine? I mean to create slaves and master locally. I tried next:

Master:

```html
> locust --master
```

Slaves:

```html
> locust --slave --master-host=127.0.0.1 --master-port=8089
```

But I am getting the error:

**You are running in distributed mode but have no slave servers connected. Please connect slaves prior to swarming.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run locust distributed on the local machine. Note that you don't need to provide ***master-host*** parameter as it defaults to ***127.0.0.1***.

First, open the terminal and start the master using this command:

> locust -f load_test_script.py --master

Then start slaves, each in a new terminal window:

> locust -f load_test_script.py --worker

For optimal performance, the number of slaves on the local machine should not excide the number of CPU cores. Check [official documentation](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html) for more info about running locust in distributed mode.

Comment: Good answer! Just to clarify what I think OP had misunderstood: the locust master-worker communication does not use the web UI/http interface (port 8089), it uses zeromq (on port 5557)

Comment: Great, that helps. The only thing is that I need to run slaves with --slave instead of --worker. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation says to use --worker not --slave. https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-distributed.html